# How do I do basis path coverage testing with a return statement?

Tags: java, testing

What are the tests sets for the following code to do basis path coverage?

```
/**
 * Attempt to rename a tag. newName must not be null.
 * Returns true/false
*/
public boolean renameTag(String oldName, String newName) { 
if(oldName.equals(newName))
       return false;

Tag tag = tags.get(oldName);
if(tag == null)
       return false;

if(tags.containsKey(newName))
       return false;

tags.remove(oldName);
tag.setName(newName);
tags.put(newName, tag);
return true;
}
```

From my [understanding](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2007/03/02/statement-branch-and-path-coverage-testing-in-java.html?page=2) basis path coverage should be:

```
TTT
FTT
TFT
TTF
```

Here are is my current test set:

```
{{oldName = "a", newName = "a", tags = {{"a", null}}},  // TTT
 {oldName = "a", newName = "b", tags = {{"b", object}}}, // FTT  
 {oldName = "a", newName = "a", tags = {{"a", object}}} // TFT
 {oldName = "a", newName = "a", tags = {}} // TTF}
```

But that does not work in this example because of the returns after the conditional is true. My tests will only test the first and second conditional and the 3rd conditional will never be testes.

How should my set of tests look to get basis path testing but using the minimal set of test?

Comment: You can still test your 3rd conditional if tag is not null right?

Comment: Yes I can still test it. But from my understanding of basis path coverage I should always do it in the specific order. I cannot find examples of how it is done when returns exist for true if cases.

Comment: {oldName = "a", newName = "b", tags = {{"a", object}, {"b", object}}. Won't this work?

Comment: I dont understand basis path coverage enough to know if just one test case is enough to say that is all I need.

Comment: You will need a positive and a negative case. Your second case serves as negative for first, third for second, fourth for third. And the last return has to happen in any case. So your code seems covered with the test cases to me.

Comment: Does it make sense? Should I explain more?

Comment: I understand what you mean. The problem I am facing is not how to write tests. It is how to get basis path coverage in specific. I want the minimal set of tests necessary to get basis path coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test cases are wrong. Thats what my guess is.

```
{{oldName = "a", newName = "a", tags = {{"a", null}}},  //For 1st if
 {oldName = "a", newName = "b", tags = {{"b", object}}}, // for second if 
 {oldName = "a", newName = "b", tags = {{"a", object}, {"b", object}} // for third if
```

Comment: I want the minimal set of tests necessary to get basis path coverage. This test set is actually node coverage, branch coverage, and full path coverage, so it has to be also basis path coverage. But what is the minimal set?

Comment: Your case is a little different coz you can't really check a TFT or a TTF, as once the first condition is true, you exit the function. Thats why the above cases are the minimal set you need to test. Makes sense?

Comment: Your basic set will be TFF, FTF, FFT. This is the minimal you need to test. You can skip the last test.